# BREAK statement in PL/pgSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, loops, plpgsql, break

How to have the `break` statement in PostgreSQL? I have the structure like this:

```sql
for() {
  for() {
    if(somecondition)
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

As per my understanding it should only break the inner `for` loop?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

There is no <strike>`BREAK`</strike> in [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html).

**[`EXIT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS-EXIT)** terminates the loop.
**[`CONTINUE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS-CONTINUE)** continues at the next iteration of the loop.
You can attach a `<<label>>` to loops and add it as parameter to each of these commands. Then you terminate / continue the *labeled* loop. Else, it concerns the *inner* loop.
**[`RETURN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)** exits from the function (so not applicable in a [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) statement).

All of this applies to procedural elements of PL/pgSQL, *not* SQL.
Code example using all three:

- [Loop in function does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257398/loop-in-function-does-not-work-as-expected/19309470#19309470)

Comment: You are correct here , I don't know why other people have voted it down here.

Comment: `EXIT` is equivalent of what the OP meant by `BREAK`. There is no BREAK in PL/pgSQL. is a bit misleading otherwise.

Comment: or you can use a RAISE EXCEPTION

Answer (score 1):

Note, that: Yes! you need the "WHEN", even if you end up (like me ;-)) with something like

```
LOOP
  ...
  IF l_my_var = 'some condition' THEN
    -- this is ok, bla
    IF l_debug_level >= 2 THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'debug 2: skipping a duplicate %', l_my_var;
    END IF;
    -- do something
    CONTINUE WHEN TRUE; -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173194/break-statement-in-pl-pgsql
  ELSE
    -- do something
  END IF;
  ...
```

which looks somewhat twisted with both IF and WHEN.

Remark to the editor:
One could make the link behind "CONTINUE" more precise: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN66440

Answer (score 1):

`BREAK` statement doesn't exit in PostgreSQL.

Instead, you can use the [EXIT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS-EXIT) in PL/pgSQL(`LANGUAGE plpgsql`) which can exit the loop anytime or when the condition is true.

For example, you can exit inner and outer loops when `num >= 2` and `num = 4` respectively as shown below:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  num INT := 0;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    LOOP
      EXIT WHEN num >= 2; -- Here
      RAISE INFO 'Inner loop:num is %.', num;
      num := num + 1;
    END LOOP;
    EXIT WHEN num = 4; -- Here
    RAISE INFO 'Outer loop:num is %.', num;
    num := num + 1;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Then, it raises the messages in the inner and outer loops, then exits the inner and outer loops when `num >= 2` and `num = 4` respectively as shown below:

```
INFO:  Inner loop:num is 0.
INFO:  Inner loop:num is 1.
INFO:  Outer loop:num is 2.
INFO:  Outer loop:num is 3.
DO
```